# Edit restriction in Microsoft Onenote

Tags: permissions, file-sharing, microsoft-onenote, user

I have multiple notebooks shared within my team. However, I want one of the notebook/page, to be restricted. Other team members should not have the access the edit a specified notebook/page. They should only be able to view it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it on a page-by-page basis. You can set an entire OneNote section to be read-only, simply find the .ONE file in your file system with Windows Explorer, right-click it and set the permissions so that only one user has the authority to write but the other users have the ability to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can password protect a section (tab).  Right click on the tab and select "Password protect this section..." this brings up the Password Protection side window.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Password protection is not the same as read-only access.

Answer (score 0):

This is not precisely what you're asking for. It's gotten more complicated, since OneNote notebooks aren't necessarily a collection of .ONE files anymore.

OneNote notebooks are now stored in SharePoint or OneDrive. For those notebooks, read-protection now becomes a matter of setting permissions at the notebook storage level.

For example, the OneNote notebook associated with a corporate SharePoint site:
[image: OneNote notebook link]

is located in its **Site Contents** > **Site Assets**
[image: Locating OneNote notebook in Site Contents > Site Assets]

and named in the form ***SharePoint site* Notebook**
[image]

Set SharePoint permissions on that Notebook to manage its access.