# Anchor text and objects to OneNote

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I teach third grade virtually during this pandemic event. I use OneNote for my class notes. Is there any way to anchor everything so that my students won't continuously delete my content?

Comment: Make the section involved Read Only so they can View but not Write (Change).  Please see this SU article for additional help.   https://superuser.com/questions/413489/edit-restriction-in-microsoft-onenote#:~:text=You%20can%20set%20an%20entire,have%20the%20ability%20to%20read.&text=You%20can%20password%20protect%20a%20section%20(tab).

Comment: Is this by any chance a feature within [OneNote Class Notebook](https://www.onenote.com/classnotebook)? It looks like there's options to distribute class materials. I haven't poked around in it, but maybe that content is locked from editing by students?

Answer (score 0):

You can make sections that are One Note files read-only.  That prevents anyone but the owner from making changes.

[https://superuser.com/questions/413489/edit-restriction-in-microsoft-onenote#:~:text=You%20can%20set%20an%20entire,have%20the%20ability%20to%20read.&text=You%20can%20password%20protect%20a%20section%20(tab)](https://superuser.com/questions/413489/edit-restriction-in-microsoft-onenote#:%7E:text=You%20can%20set%20an%20entire,have%20the%20ability%20to%20read.&text=You%20can%20password%20protect%20a%20section%20(tab))

> You can't do it on a page-by-page basis. You can set an entire OneNote
> section to be read-only, simply find the .ONE file in your file system
> with Windows Explorer, right-click it and set the permissions so that
> only one user has the authority to write but the other users have the
> ability to read.

You can also Password Protect a Tab.  Right click on the Tab and select Password Protect.

Screen shot to help

[image]

You should, of course, have a complete backup of your One Note files on another computer that you can recover from. I keep my own One Note files backed up each day.